# What do asterisks mean in the ledger?

Tags: trading, kraken

I recently placed an order with Kraken (or tried to anyway, the site was giving me lots of errors and timeouts) Seemingly a trade went through after several attempts.

However, my account balance now has an asterisk in it, for example

```
Lumen (XLM) *2,038.04006    $0.2002
```

And the ledger looks like this

```
12-14-17 22:59:26 -0500 Trade   Lumen (XLM) *1,040.76635    *2.72629    *2,038.04006
```

What does the asterisk indicate?

**Update** - I now check the order history, and Kraken claims the order is cancelled - however, the XLM coin are available for Transfer, and the Bitcoins I used to make the purchase are no longer available.  I think Kraken either has something very strange in their user interface or the money was lost somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk is the currency symbol for XLM, like $ or ฿.